# Decode equivalent in postgres

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

There is no equivalent to the Oracle's `DECODE()` Function In Postgres. Is there anyone who wrote decode as a Function?

Comment: You might have better luck if you describe what that function does. As it is anyone that knows Postgres but not Oracle will be completely unable to provide an answer without researching that first.

Comment: There's no short-form lookup like `decode`, but you can use the SQL-standard `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is an equivalent. It's called a [`CASE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html) statement.

There are two forms of CASE:

**Simple CASE:**

```
CASE search-expression
    WHEN expression [, expression [ ... ]] THEN
      statements
  [ WHEN expression [, expression [ ... ]] THEN
      statements
    ... ]
  [ ELSE
      statements ]
END CASE;
```

**Searched CASE:**

```
CASE
    WHEN boolean-expression THEN
      statements
  [ WHEN boolean-expression THEN
      statements
    ... ]
  [ ELSE
      statements ]
END CASE;
```

`CASE` statements are easier to read; I prefer these over `decode()` in Oracle.

Comment: Except one much be careful around NULLs, as Oracle's `decode()` considers NULLs are a _regular_ value for comparison, not the (weird) SQL tri-valued logic. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Oracle_to_Postgres_Conversion#Decode also warns about it.

Comment: `CASE` is an equivalent to the ORACLE `CASE` function, which is the same. Correct answer would be "There is no equivalent"

Comment: @Thanthia: please lookup the definition of equivalent

Comment: `CASE` is for sure easier to read, but *longer*, so time to time `decode` is handy.

Comment: This is the CASE statement, but the question seems to be about a function, that can be used like SELECT DECODE(...) FROM DUAL; There is also a CASE expression in both Oracle and Postgresql that is similar but ends with END, like SELECT CASE ... END FROM DUAL. That is what can be used instead of DECODE.

Answer (score 4):

If you are used to Oracle specific functions, you might want to install PostgreSQL extension [`orafce`](http://pgxn.org/dist/orafce/).

Among other Oracle specific functions, `orafce` also implements `DECODE` - one that you are looking for.

If you are running on Ubuntu, you will simply need to install package [`postgresql-9.1-orafce`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/postgresql-9.1-orafce) to make `orafce` available in your PostgreSQL server.

Comment: in windows ,how can i install this one??

Comment: It should be possible - I have never tried. Ok, I tried Postgres on Windows, but it worked so much slower compared to Linux, that I never looked back. If you care about performance, you really should NOT run PostgreSQL on Windows - look at [this answer by one of PostgreSQL developers](http://serverfault.com/questions/222430/is-postgresql-suited-to-one-os-is-it-better-on-linux-than-windows).

Comment: how to install on windows..can u pls share download link

Comment: If you are willing to install `mingw` and other build tools, you should be able to build PostgreSQL from source, and then compile and install `orafce` using standard `pgxs` extension compiling mechanism - it [all in documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/extend-pgxs.html). Most people prefer to install Postgres from packages, not compile it from source - most of the time this is real showstopper. That's why Ubuntu offering PostgreSQL and all other extensions like `orafce` as standard packages makes things so simple on Linux.

Comment: i think..then it is better to use 'case' statement

Answer (score 4):

You can combine NULLIF with COALESCE:

SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(value, 0), newValue) FROM table;

Font: [Coalesce for zero instead of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47918929/coalesce-for-zero-instead-of-null)

Comment: Obrigado for sharing an equivalent **function**! In some ways this is more succinct than oracle's decode - ie. `decode(column1, 0, column2, column1)` becomes `coalesce(nullif(column1, 0), column2)`. In other situations a case statement will have to do

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the main answer, "END CASE" does not apply if the case expression is used in the select, just use "END".

Oracle:

```
select decode(1+1, 2, 'yes', 'no') from dual
```

Postgres:

```
select case 1+1 when 2 then 'yes' else 'no' end
```