# RFM analysis with Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am trying to create RFM analysis with Postgresql query. However, i haven't fully completed the query for the Recency dimension.
The query inspired in this article 
"https://cooldata.wordpress.com/2014/03/25/an-all-sql-way-to-automate-rfm-scoring/ "
The criteria of the Recency dimension was

1. Last order within 2 months = 5
2. Last order within 4 months = 4
3. Last order within 6 months = 3
4. Last order within 8 months = 2
5. Last order within 10 months = 1

and below is the query i've been trying to finish

```
WITH rfm AS

(SELECT email,
 SUM((total_incl_tax)) AS cash,
 MAX(decode(order_order.order_date, 2016-01-01, 5, 2016-02-01, 4, 2016-03-01, 3, 2016-04-01, 2, 201605-01, 1)) AS recency,
 COUNT(DISTINCT(order_date)) AS frequency
 FROM order_order

 GROUP BY email)


SELECT rfm.email,
CASE
WHEN rfm.cash >= 2000000 THEN 5
WHEN rfm.cash > 1500000 THEN 4
WHEN rfm.cash > 1000000 THEN 3
WHEN rfm.cash > 500000 THEN 2
WHEN rfm.frequency > 4 THEN 5
WHEN rfm.frequency = 4 THEN 4
WHEN rfm.frequency = 3 THEN 3
WHEN rfm.frequency = 2 THEN 2
WHEN rfm.frequency = 1 THEN 1
else 1

END  + rfm.frequency AS rfm_score
--+ Five_years.recency

FROM rfm
GROUP BY rfm.email, rfm.cash,rfm.frequency
ORDER BY rfm.email
```

The error was :

```
ERROR: function decode(timestamp with time zone, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 186
```

and i assume the error was in this line

```
MAX(decode(order_order.order_date, 2016-01-01, 5, 2016-02-01, 4, 2016-03-01, 3, 2016-04-01, 2, 2016-05-01, 1)) AS recency
```

Are there any suggestion in modifying the error line into the criteria stated for the recency dimension? thanks

Comment: Where [in the Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions.html) did you find the `decode()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `decode()` function in Postgres. You can substitute this with another `CASE` statement:

```
WITH rfm AS
(
     SELECT email,
     SUM((total_incl_tax)) AS cash,
     MAX(
         CASE
          WHEN order_order.order_date = '2016-01-01' THEN 5
          WHEN order_order.order_date = '2016-02-01' THEN 4
          WHEN order_order.order_date = '2016-03-01' THEN 3
          WHEN order_order.order_date = '2016-04-01' THEN 2
          WHEN order_order.order_date = '2016-05-01' THEN 1
         END
        )   as recency,
     COUNT(DISTINCT(order_date)) AS frequency
     FROM order_order
     GROUP BY email
 )
SELECT rfm.email,
CASE
    WHEN rfm.cash >= 2000000 THEN 5
    WHEN rfm.cash > 1500000 THEN 4
    WHEN rfm.cash > 1000000 THEN 3
    WHEN rfm.cash > 500000 THEN 2
    WHEN rfm.frequency > 4 THEN 5
    WHEN rfm.frequency = 4 THEN 4
    WHEN rfm.frequency = 3 THEN 3
    WHEN rfm.frequency = 2 THEN 2
    WHEN rfm.frequency = 1 THEN 1
    else 1
END  + rfm.frequency + rfm.recency AS rfm_score
FROM rfm
GROUP BY rfm.email, rfm.cash,rfm.frequency
ORDER BY rfm.email
```

Further reading here: [Decode equivalent in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262351/decode-equivalent-in-postgres)