# Coalesce for zero instead of null

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple company table which inconsistently use column name `turnover` and `revenue`. The table currently looks like this:

```
company, turnover, revenue
A, 10000, 0
B, 0, 2500
C, 0, 3000
4, 23000, 0
```

I know how to use coalesce to choose between null and value, but there the value to be discarded is zero instead of null.

The end result that I want is:

```
company, revenue
A, 10000
B, 2500
C, 3000
D, 23000
```

The query that I'm imagining is:

```
select company, coalesce_for_zero(turnover, revenue) as revenue from
company_profile;
```

How do I write a query that can achieve coalesce-like results for zero?

Comment: There is no *coalesce for zero*. You need to write a `CASE` to do do this.

Comment: if your values are always positive, you can use just `greatest(turnover, revenue)` - it won't take first not zero value literally, but in result it will

Comment: @VaoTsun: `GREATEST` returns the maximum of its arguments. So `GREATEST(1, 2)` will return the wrong result.

Comment: ah, surely - I thought it could be zero or number :) too early in the morning here

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You can combine [`NULLIF`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-conditional.html) with `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT company, COALESCE(NULLIF(turnover, 0), revenue) AS revenue FROM company_profile;
```

`NULLIF` returns `NULL` if it's arguments are equal, and the first argument otherwise.

Comment: You can even coalesce as many nullify as you want, thanks, saved me!

Answer (score -4):

You can coalesce with 0 as a parameter

```
coalesce(turnover, revenue, 0)
```

Comment: I believe this is not what the OP wanted, this will return 0 if `turnover` and `revenue` are null, but we want to do that if they are 0.