# Redshift ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric:

Tags: amazon-redshift

Below is the original code from oracle DB

```
select 
decode(acc_number,
'', acc_number, 
'123'||acc_number) as acc_number
from table1
```

i want to convert it on redshift and it is not working

> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric:

i try to cast '123' into numeric

```
 select 
decode(acc_number,
'', acc_number, 
'123'::numeric||acc_number) as acc_number
from table1
```

but it still not working

update on using case when on redshift

```
select 
case when acc_number = '' then acc_number
  else '123'||acc_number 
end
from table1
```

same error

> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric:

Comment: Decode is not Postgresql syntax, see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262351/decode-equivalent-in-postgres

Comment: What data type is acc_number?  It looks like you are string concatenating 2 numeric values and want a numeric result, no?  Or is acc_number a string?

Comment: It looks like the issue might be with comparing acc_number, a numeric, with the empty string ''.  If this is correct then I think you want to test against NULL, not the empty string.  But you also look to be doing a string concatenate on acc_number.  Are you trying to do this:  decode(acc_number is NULL, true, acc_number, ('123'||acc_number::text)::numeric) - assuming I have want is happening correctly sussed out.  BTW DECODE() is perfectly fine on Redshift.